# removeRow using XSSF libraries is not working

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi, xssf

I tried the below code, but it's not working

```
    File src = new File("E:\\TestData.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(src);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("test");
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);
    sheet.removeRow(row);
```

Note: Not getting any error also

Comment: What isn't working? Wrong row removed? Error opening excel? Row removed in wrong sheet? Other?

Comment: You have to save the changes using `java.io.FileOutputStream`, see https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-example-to-update-existing-excel-files-using-apache-poi

Answer (score 2):

```
You need to save file after row deletion
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(File Path);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();
```